# When to use setWidth, setHeight, setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w,h))?

Tags: android, button

I am confused on when to use setWidth, and setHeight? It usually don't work.

What always work is setLayoutParams.

This will work.

```
sampleButton = new Button(this);

                sampleButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(65, 65));
```

This will not work.

```
sampleButton = new Button(this);
sampleButton.setHeight(65);
sampleButton.setWidth(65);
```

Or maybe there are some initialisation for this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just looked at the `Button`'s source code (which is a subclass of `TextView`):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setHeight%28int%29

here is the method for setHeight

```
public void setHeight(int pixels) {
    mMaximum = mMinimum = pixels;
    mMaxMode = mMinMode = PIXELS;

    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}
```

now in the `onMeasure` method, `mMaximum` and `mMaxMode` are used here

```
    int unpaddedHeight = height - getCompoundPaddingTop() - getCompoundPaddingBottom();
    if (mMaxMode == LINES && mLayout.getLineCount() > mMaximum) {
        unpaddedHeight = Math.min(unpaddedHeight, mLayout.getLineTop(mMaximum));
    }
```

It looks like the setheight doesn't really overwrite the internal height parameters, more just sets flags for layout.

Changing the layout params (which are what are actually referenced when the view is laying itself out) seem to inform the view that it actually needs to be that hight

**TLDR; setHeight has more to do with the line height of the text than the height of the view**