# Android- setWidth() of Button doesn't work, if ViewGroup's width is 'match_parent'/'fill_parent' in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I defined a LinearLayout as root element in activity_main.xml.

CASE 1: From onCreate() I tried to add Button in this Vertical LinearLayout, what confused me is, as per Google's API, I tried to call setWidth(20) on button before adding it in ViewGroup, but Button occupied width 'match_parent' rather than 20dp.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/first_layout">
    </LinearLayout>

//Inside onCreate() of activity..    
    LinearLayout firstLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_layout);
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setText(R.string.click_on_me);
            button.setWidth(20);
            firstLayout.addView(button);
```

[image: Case 1]

CASE 2:on setting layout_width of LinearLayout to 'wrap_content', and calling setWidth(20), It now considered given explicit width value i.e 20dp.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/first_layout">
</LinearLayout>

//Inside onCreate() method
LinearLayout firstLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_layout);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(R.string.click_on_me);
        button.setWidth(20);//In this case, its working
        firstLayout.addView(button);
```

[image]

CASE 3: Finally, removing my custom call to setWidth(20), Button acquired width as 'wrap_content'.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/first_layout">

</LinearLayout>

//Inside onCreate() method.
LinearLayout firstLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_layout);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(R.string.click_on_me);        
        firstLayout.addView(button);
```

[image]

Ques : So it is clear by case-2, that using LayoutParams is not necessary, if I wish to explicitly use setWidth() method.Then In Case 4: i.e LinearLayout's width set as 'match_parent' and button.setWidth(20) is also called.
But why Button is still not taking explicitly given width value, again output is exactly same as CASE 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define an appropriate `LayoutParams` for your button view. Then add it to your `firstLayout`.

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.height = XX;
params.width = XX;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: But API of setWidth() says "Makes the TextView exactly this many pixels wide. You could do the same thing by specifying this number in the LayoutParams."
I think this means that, its not necessary I must use LayoutParams approach, as by calling setWidth() I'm trying to define the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand why using `Layoutparams` is necessary when you dynamically create Button or any component.

Suppose if your using LayoutParams to Button to give width. Then When we set the layout params of the Button, we are telling the parent layout (that is LinearLayout in your case) rendering the Button, to set the specified height and width for the view. Therefore, it works fine while rendering.

In case 1 as you told it is not affecting setwidth of 20 that is because the Button has a minimum width of 64dip by default. Set it to 0 before setting the width.

```
btn.setMinimumWidth(0);
```

This link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132048/when-to-use-setwidth-setheight-setlayoutparamsnew-linearlayout-layoutparamsw) could give you some help.

Comment: I don't understand WHY LayoutParams is necessary. A button should have 4 properties, left, top, width and height. Please explain WHY these properties are not sufficient? A general principle in programming is to use meaningful names. So a name like 'setWidth' should set the width. In Android setWidth does NOT set the width. WHY WHY WHY WHY ...